# Using a Custom Element that takes a `ref` attribute with React?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use a Custom HTML Element (aka WebComponent), that takes a `ref`-attribute.

```
React.createElement('tei-ptr', { ref: 'something' }, null)
```

fails of course, because `ref` is interpreted by React in the sense of React.createRef().

Is there a way to pass the ref attribute, maybe similar to `className` or `htmlFor`?

Comment: are you meant to pass ref to your custom element ? if so made a demo on this, check this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-snxy5z

Comment: Sorry if that was not clear: I simply need a way to create a custom element with `React.createElement` and pass it an attribute that is called `ref` - while avoiding the naming collision with React interpreting a `ref` attribute in a special sense.